# My future method is not working fine, while using flutter builder widget, Where did I go wrong?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

Here is my stateful widget and url is a property pass it to the widget from parent widget. I don't know where did I go wrong?? I created a future builder widget that has getData() as a future. But the print statement inside was not executed ever. Why is that and it returns me always null value, and this results  me a red container appearing on screen and not the table widget.

```
class TimeTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final url;
  const TimeTable({Key? key,required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TimeTableState createState() => _TimeTableState();
}

class _TimeTableState extends State<TimeTable> {

  Future<List<Train>> getData() async{
    final list =  await TrainClient(url: widget.url).getName();
    print("this line not executed");
    return list;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: FutureBuilder(
         future: getData(),
        builder: (context,projectSnap){
          if(projectSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.none ||
              projectSnap.data == null) {
            return Container(color: Colors.red,);
          }
            return buildDataTable(trains: projectSnap.data);


        }));


  }
}
```

getData is a future method and it returns a list, The list gets printed when I call that object Train Client. I had my print statement inside TrainClient class to check whether the list is created successfully.

Here is the code of TrainClient

```
class TrainClient {
  final String url;
  TrainClient({required this.url});

  Future<List<Train>> getName() async {

    final uri = Uri.parse(url);

    final response = await get(uri);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       print("ulla");
       final data = json.decode(response.body);

       final result = data["RESULTS"]["directTrains"]["trainsList"];
       final list =  result.map((json) => Train.fromJson(json));
       print(list);
       return list;

    }else{

      throw Exception();

    }



  }

}
```

The TrainClient class has no error since it printed the list successfully as shown below

```
(Instance of 'Train', Instance of 'Train', Instance of 'Train', ..., Instance of 'Train', Instance of 'Train')
```

Comment: Why are you using `projectSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.none`? Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You should always obtain future earlier (in initState/didChangeDependencies).
Each time your build is executed, new future is created. So it never finishes, if your widget rebuilds often.

```
late final _dataFuture = getData();

...

FutureBuilder(
     future: _dataFuture,
     builder: (context,projectSnap){
...
     }
);
```